# IOS dispatch_async passing NSString from thread to main view

Tags: ios, dispatch-async

First post - please be gentle.

I am trying to port a remote control application from Android over to iPhone and am having some difficulty with the intra-thread communication using dispatch_async on a method in the main view.

The application has a separate ControlPanel class which takes care of communications to a remote client. The ControlPanel comms object is instantiated as a background thread which takes care of continuous network comms to a device and I need the background thread to pass simple text strings to the UI thread - updating a textfield.

I have looked at many examples, but none seem to deal with definitions and I've been going round in circles with this.  How do I define the method in the ControlPanel class ?  I have tried various ways of defining, but not making any headway.  Am I missing something simple ?  The updateKeypadDisplay in the viewDidLoad was suggested as the way to do this, but I don't understand the syntax enough to see where I am going wrong.

```
/*  
 *   In the ControlPanel.m class the thread does stuff and wants to update the UI:
 */

NSString * kpString = @"String Updated By Process";

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.updateKeypadDisplay(kpString);    // << This call gives an error - property not found on object of type ControlPanel                          
});


/*  
 *   In the ControlPanel.h header :
 */
- (void)updateKeypadDisplay:(void (^)(NSString *kpString))block;




/*  
 *   In the ViewController .m
 */
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    kpdisplay.text = @"Initial String";
    backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.sss.tt.bgqueue", NULL);  

    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
        self.panelobj = [[ControlPanel alloc ]init];
        [self.panelobj connectPanel];
    });

    //   This was suggested as the way to define the method to update the main UI kpdisplay text field, but
    //    I cannot get the syntax right.   I'm also unsure the definitions are correct in the headers.
    //
    //       [ControlPanel updateKeypadDisplay::^(NSData *kpString) {
    //       self.kpdisplay.text = kpString;
    //       }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to update the UI from a background thread you need to call dispatch async to the Main Thread (which is where all UI is handled).

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    NSLog(@"I can update UI elements here!");
});
```

Comment: This is what I'm trying to achieve as you can already see the dispatch_async onto the main queue from my example code. From my code above, the main UI thread dispatches an async background thread which performs networking tasks. The background thread runs continuously and needs to dispatch_async back onto the main thread to update the UI. I don't know how to define the main UI thread update method call within the background thread.